# CKEDITOR 4 - dtd: If i change b element values, others also change like p elements

Tags: dtd, ckeditor4.x

I'm working with CKEDITOR 4 and I have added a new element to dtd. My custom element can be contained in a '**p**' element but I don't want that it can be contained in a '**b**' element. Then, now I have this:

```
alert( !!CKEDITOR.dtd[ 'p' ][ 'mycustomtag' ] ); // **true**

alert( !!CKEDITOR.dtd[ 'b' ][ 'mycustomtag' ] ); // **true**
```

So I do the following:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.[ 'b' ][ 'mycustomtag' ] = 0;
```

but after this I check it again and:

```
alert( !!CKEDITOR.dtd[ 'p' ][ 'mycustomtag' ] ); // **false**

alert( !!CKEDITOR.dtd[ 'b' ][ 'mycustomtag' ] ); // **false**
```

It seems like b and p element are grouped in some way... but I want to get this:

```
alert( !!CKEDITOR.dtd[ 'p' ][ 'mycustomtag' ] ); // **true**

alert( !!CKEDITOR.dtd[ 'b' ][ 'mycustomtag' ] ); // **false**
```

I can't find a way to change only element b... Anyone know how to get it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include code blocks. Every line of code should start with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution.

Consists in redefining the dtd elements (b and p) in whole and not in part, like this:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.b = { '#': 1, a: 1, abbr: 1, *mycustomtag: 0*, acronym: 1, applet: 1, 
area: 1, audio: 1, font: 1, i: 1, iframe: 1, ... }

CKEDITOR.dtd.p = { '#': 1, a: 1, abbr: 1, *mycustomtag: 1*, acronym: 1, applet: 1, 
area: 1, audio: 1, font: 1, i: 1, iframe: 1, ... }
```

I don't know if it is the most elegant solution, but it worked out well.

kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Need clone original object:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.p = CKEDITOR.tools.clone(CKEDITOR.dtd.p);
CKEDITOR.dtd.p.mycustomtag = 1;
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.b = CKEDITOR.tools.clone(CKEDITOR.dtd.b);
CKEDITOR.dtd.b.mycustomtag = 0;
```

Because object is shared with multiple tags in DTD (`p` and `b` share same object = same setting).